# Remove adding additional spaces before the brackets when entering RANGES

Tags: vba, excel-2016

How can I stop Excel, visual basic editor from adding additional spaces before the brackets when entering RANGES :

```
Sub myrange()
     Range("A1:A5")
End Sub

'This becomes 

Sub myrange()
      Range ("A1:A5")
End Sub
```

' Because of the extra space after Range it causes a compile error

Comment: How do you enter the code? Type it? Paste it? When does it add the space?

Comment: If I Paste it in there isn't a problem and the program runs, however If I decide to add more code to experiment with by typing another row and copying parts of the original code then as I type and finish the line with return then the extra space is automatically added behind the bracket and the program will not run showing the error.  If I then try to delete the space and move my cursor away from the line the space reappears.