# VBA coding format changes automatically

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vbe

I am trying to use VBA in Excel. It was working fine then I started to have the following issue:

When I type the code it would reformat automatically causing the code to be formatted incorrectly, here's a simple example.

I type:
`Range("a2")`

Before I have a chance to put the period at the end the VBE adds a space between Range and the first bracket:
`Range ("a2")`

So then what happens is that when I type the period the cursor has remained in the same position so it is entered inside the last bracket:
`Range ("a2".)`

I delete the period place the cursor outside the bracket and add `.Select` and the VBE then automatically takes the space out between range and the first bracket and now it's correctly formatted as
`Range("a2").Select`

When I'm typing `Range` it stays in black but when I type the first `(` the text then turns red. Whenever I type the text changes to black but then turns immediately red when I stop typing.

I've rebooted my machine. I've turned the auto syntax option on and off. To be on the latest versions I upgraded my MacOS to Sonoma from Monterey and reinstalled Excel but I'm still having the same issue.

I'm expecting to be able to type `Range("a2").Select` without the VBE putting the `.` inside the last bracket which I then have to delete and re-enter outside the bracket and complete the rest of the line of code.

This is a simple piece of code but the formatting issue makes writing more complex code practically impossible.

This is making VBA in Excel unusable... please help...

Comment: I have been able to get the similar issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174588/remove-adding-additional-spaces-before-the-brackets-when-entering-ranges) but that's more due to just typing a range. Actually trying to do something with the range (even though you shouldn't need `Select` almost ever), I've never encountered this. Have you tried using a different file to test in? I even tried naming a function/sub "Range" and then typing your case in a different sub just in case that was something but also nothing strange happened.

Comment: Hi, I tried it in an existing piece of code but it still had the same problem. 

In a newly created clean file with a new macro that only had this line of code it also still has the same issue?

Comment: Side note, you probably don't need to `Select` that range, and `Range` should probably be qualified with an explicit `Worksheet` object. Sounds like your VBE has "auto syntax check" enabled, which is utterly annoying indeed.